# SVN ignore folder and files during import

Tags: svn, version-control, versioning, svnignore

I need to use SVN in command line mode. The subversion that i'm using is 1.6.

I have this project to do the versioning for the first time:

```
/myproj/a/fileA.txt  
/myproj/b/fileB.txt  
/myproj/c/fileC.txt  
/myproj/log/fileLOG1.txt  
/myproj/log/fileLOG2.txt  
/myproj/configure.txt
```

I would like to import the project but I would like to exclude the directory *log* (with all contained files) and the *configure* file.
How to exclude all directory content and the file and import only the files in folders a,b,c?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a Subversion repository set up at some remote place, you could...

First create a new folder in your repository. You can do this directly by specifying the folder by URL:

```
svn mkdir --parents https://your.svn.server/folder/myproj/trunk
```

Creating a `trunk` directory is a good idea, so you'll have the project set up properly and can later create `tags` and `branches` directories besides `trunk`. `--parents` tells Subversion to create intermediate directories if necessary.

Then switch into your project folder and check out this new trunk folder:

```
cd myproj
svn co https://your.svn.server/folder/myproj/trunk .
```

Add all folders you want to have under version control:

```
svn add a b c
```

And ignore files and folders you don't want to be under version control. This way they will not show up as local changes any more.

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

This will open an editor (which one this is depends on how you configured Subversion). Each line contains an item to be ignored:

```
configure.txt
log
```

Then save and exit the editor. Now check the status of your local working copy:

```
svn status
```

This should show an `A` mark in front of items in your folders `a`, `b`, and `c`, indicating that these files and folders will be added. `configure.txt` and `log` should not be visible at all, because they are ignored.

Now you can commit the first version of your project:

```
svn commit -m "Added first version of my project"
```

Comment: So you suggest me to do not use the `import` command but use `add` and `commit` instead. I've got another question: when I use `svn propedit svn:ignore .`, is there a way to ignore all files in a folder?

Comment: As far as I know you can't tell `import` to leave away certain files or folders. `checkout`, `add`, and `commit` is one way to go. Another way is: move away files you don't want in the project, then do `import`, then move them back into the project, and ignore them. You can use wildcards `*` in `svn:ignore`. If you ignore a folder, like I did with the folder `log` in the example above, the folder and all contents will be ignored. If you want to have the folder under version control but ignore all files in it, add the folder, `cd` into it, and then do `svn:ignore` with `*` (ignore all files).